# V-model to dynamically created object in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array, I want to dynamically create objects in the array and `v-model` an input to it, this is what my code looks like:

This is the array

```js
new_questions:{
    questionrecord: []
}
```

This is the input

```html
<div class="form-fields" v-for="(field, index) in question_fields">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" v-model="new_questions.questionrecord[index].questionresponse">
            <option value="single_answer">Single Answer (For regular question)</option>
            <option value="multiple_answer">Multiple Answer (For situational judgement question)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect to have an array that looks like

```js
new_questions:{
    questionrecord: [
        {
            questiontype: "single_answer"
        },
        {
            questiontype: "multiple_answer"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

But I get an error:

`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'questionresponse' of undefined`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Seems like questionrecord[index] is undefined. Are you sure you're there is data loaded into the questionrecord?

Comment: What's store in `question_fields`?

Comment: @Javas `question_fields` is just a counter. 
`question_fields: 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V-Model is only syntactic sugar for `@input=".."` and `:value=".."`

To manipulate data the way you described it might be necessary to distinguish the two and write a `setterMethod` that can handle dynamic (and possibly non-existant) properties.

Depending on the structure of your data, on whether you want to handle properties on different nested levels, etc., your `setterMethod` can become a little complex. Helpers like `lodash.setWith` could help out a bit.

A very specifig example for your case:

```
<template>
...
  <div class="form-fields" v-for="(field, index) in question_fields">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control"
       :value="new_questions.questionrecord[index].questionresponse"
       @input="setValue($event.target.value, index)"
      >
        <option value="single_answer">Single Answer (For regular question)</option>
        <option value="multiple_answer">Multiple Answer (For situational judgement question)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      new_questions: {
        questionrecord: [],
      }
    };
  },

  created() {
    // prepopulate your questionrecord array so you don't throw TypeErrors
    const dummyArray = Array(this.question_fields.length);
    this.new_questions.questionrecord.push(...dummyArray);
  },

  methods() {
    setValue(value, index) {
      const newRecord = {
        questionresponse: value,
      };
      // in order to create responsive array entries in vue, you have to use native array methods - don't set the value by index
      // (e.g. this.new_questions.questionrecorcd[index] = newRecord);
      this.new_questions.questionrecord.splice(index, 1, newRecord);
      // Object properties would need to be created with Vue.set(rootObj, key, value);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how looks your `question_fields`, but I tested with some dummy values and this code works for me.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      question_fields: ['test', 'test1'],
     new_questions:{
          questionrecord: [
              {
                  questiontype: "single_answer"
              },
              {
                  questiontype: "multiple_answer"
              }
          ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="form-fields" v-for="(field, index) in question_fields">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" v-model="new_questions.questionrecord[index].questionresponse">
        <option value="single_answer">Single Answer (For regular question)</option>
        <option value="multiple_answer">Multiple Answer (For situational judgement question)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <pre>{{new_questions.questionrecord}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked for you because you've already populated your `questionrecord` array. Look at the first code block, my `questionrecord` array is empty. I'm expecting the values to be dynamically created. My `question_fields` is just a "counter" as such 
`question_fields: 1`